# what am i doing wrong with these classes and objects

Tags: python, class, object

Write a program to store student details in a class. The information should include a

studentnumber, ﬁrst name, surname and username.
Include a function that returns the e-mail address of the student. You construct the emaila ddress by adding "@coventry.ac.uk" to the username. So, Joe Blogs, with username
blogsj would get the e-mail address blogsj@coventry.ac.uk

2 Task 2

Create a program that uses the class from task 1 to collect a list of student records from
the user and allow them to be listed, with e-mail addresses.
You should include a menu system for the user.

```
#Python Lab9 Task1 & Task2
class student(object):
    def _init_(self,student_ID,name,surname,username):
        self.student_ID = student_ID
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.username = username

    def email(self):
        return self.username, "@coventry.ac.uk"
    def _str_(self):
        return "%d %s %s %s"%(self.student_ID,self.name,self.surname,self.username)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    students=[]
    user=""

    while user not in ["Q","q"]:
        print "Menu"
        print "1. Show student detail"
        print "2. Create new student detail"
        print "3. Quit"

        user=raw_input(">")
        if user=="1":
            for i in students:
                print i

        elif user=="2":
            print "Creating a new student detail"
            print "-----------------------------"

            student_ID=raw_input("Student ID:")
            name=raw_input("First Name:")
            surname=raw_input("Surname:")
            username=raw_input("Username:")

            s = student(student_ID,name,surname,username)
            students.append(s)

        elif user=="3":
            exit
```

Answer (score 2):

You need *double* underscores for `__init__` and `__str__`:

```
class student(object):
    def __init__(self,student_ID,name,surname,username):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
```

Here is a [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization).

---

Also, `exit` won't work unless you invoke it by placing `()` after it:

```
elif user=="3":
    exit()
```

---

Finally, because `self.student_ID` will be a string, you need to replace the `%d` on this line with `%s`:

```
return "%s %s %s %s"%(self.student_ID,self.name,self.surname,self.username)
```

`%d` is only used for integers.

Comment: Thank you that helped but im also having an issue with line 12 (return "%d %s %s %s"%(self.student_ID,self.name,self.surname,self.username)

Comment: @user3083481 - Right.  That problem is because `self.student_ID` is a string but `%d` is looking for an integer.  See my edit.

Comment: Technically, `exit` without `()` will kill the program, but with a `NameError` instead of a `SystemExit`

Comment: @SethMMorton - At least in Python 2.7+, `exit` is defined under [`__builtins__.exit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#exit). Not invoking it though will do nothing (just like the other built-ins).  However, you would be right if you launch Python with the [`-S`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-S) flag (which disables the `site` module).

Comment: @iCodez Hmm... I seem to remember getting a `NameError` on 2.7, but my memory could be failing me.  Either way, good to know!